# Why is Hyper-V automatically creating AVHDX and merging?

Tags: server, hyper-v

I have a fresh Hyper-V installation with 1 VM both running Server 2012 R2.

The host has SAS drives internally and SAS drives via a DAS, all in Raid 5.

I have created VHDX files on volumes on both internal and external R5 volumes for each data drive for the VM

On the VM, I've copied over a lot of data from another server.

I have noticed several AVHDX files created and the server Status is Merge in Progress.

The merge is taking a long time (days) and using 100% of the drive's IO.

So, my question is why has Hyper-V created these AVHDX files and what can i do to either stop it happening again or make it happen quicker?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You have either created checkpoints on your Hyper-V box, or you have enabled Hyper-V replica.
Do the needful there to remove/stop the avhdx files